# Rear and front audio jacks being recognized as same

Tags: audio, windows-registry

I want to make rear and front audio jacks being recognized as same for my Realtek audio **without the dirver/software.**
In linux it was pretty simple as I remember But in windows I found that there are options stored in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e96c-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0000\GlobalSettings`
from 0000 to the end.

making `EnableDynamicDevices` to 0 frees the jack detection but it makes two different channels. I want to make the front and rear jack play the same channel. (or recognized as same)

Is it possible with registry editing? (no Realtek driver or buying physical splitter and such)

Comment: You could perhaps use a product such as the free and open-source [Equalizer APO](https://sourceforge.net/projects/equalizerapo/).

Comment: @harrymc well I could not find anyway to make the channels or devices play eachother but it seems it fixed some of my "other" audio issues. so kudos to you.

Comment: Did it fix enough "other" audio issues to be counted as an answer?

Comment: no it just fixed my bad microphone. I would up vote your comment If the button ever appears but with the rep I'm having now it's not showing.